# How do I find out of these vectors are coplanar?

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors

I have a task stating this:

> Determine if the following vectors are coplanar.
> Assume that $v_1$, $v_2$ and $v_3$ are not coplanar.
>
> $w_1=4\vec v_1+3\vec v_2$
>
> $w_2=\vec v_2+4\vec v_3$
>
> $w_3=-\vec v_1-3\vec v_3$

I don't quite understand how I'll do this when I do not know the values of any of the vectors. Also, what significance does the information "$v_1$, $v_2$ and $v_3$ are not coplanar" have in terms of the solution? I'm guessing knowing that helps decide whether they're coplanar or not, but I can't see how.

Comment: Time to throw off the chains of concrete vectors and start embracing abstract ones :) blf's hint hits the nail on the head!

Comment: How can three vectors not be coplanar? Clearly $S=\operatorname{sp}\{v_1-v_3,v_2-v_3\}$ is at most a two dimensional space, hence a plane (or contained on one), and $S+\{v_3\}$ is just a translated plane.

Comment: 3 vectors can easily be non-coplanar in 3D space. Two vectors can't, but 3 can.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint: in a 3-dimensional space, $v_1, v_2, v_3$ being not coplanar is equivalent to saying that they are linearly independent, i.e., they form a basis. The question is to show that the same holds (or doesn't hold) for $w_1, w_2, w_3$.

Comment: What does it mean for vectors to form a basis? I'm not familiar with that term..

Comment: @Threethumb A basis is a spanning set of linearly independent vectors. Any vector in your vector space can be written as a linear combination of basis vectors.

Comment: Ah, I see. So the solution lies in the fact that linearly independent vectors, while not able to be written as linear combinations of each other, can be used together to write any other vector as a linear combination of those linearly independent vectors?

Comment: @Threethumb Yes, if you have _enough_ linearly independent vectors to span the vector space. However, if you have too few, you can't.

Comment: How do I determine whether there are enough vectors to span the vector space?

Comment: @Threethumb In an $n$-dimensional space, a basis will have $n$ vectors.

Comment: Oh right, that makes sense. I remember figuring out that in an $n$-dimensional space, $n+1$ vectors will always be linearly dependent. Which I now realize is for this exact reason.

Comment: I'm still a bit unsure how I'd go about proving whether these vectors form a basis or not, though. Wouldn't they all do so by default, since the $w$'s is being represented as the linear combination of two linearly independent vectors? Or is there some type of calculation I have to do, because there is no default answer for a problem like this?

Comment: @Threethumb You need to show whether the definition of "linearly independent" holds: that is, the only way that $c_1 \vec{w_1} + c_2 \vec{w_2} + c_3 \vec{w_3}= 0$ could be true is if $c_1=c_2=c_3=0$. However, you can see that this is not the case.

Comment: Ah, so I can say they are coplanar, because it's demonstrable that the $w$ vectors can be linear combinations of each other - thus making them 3 linearly dependent vectors, which also means they are coplanar (since 3 linearly dependent vectors and 3 coplanar vectors are both defined by the ability to represent one vector as a linear combination of the two others)?

Comment: @copper.hat I don't see why $0$, $e_1$, and $e_2$ are not coplanar; could you clarify?

Comment: @blf: My apologies, I was off in space. I read collinear. I will delete my comment.

Comment: @blf: Actually, I am a little confused. You can **always** find a plane that passes through three points, so how can $v_1,v_2,v_3$ not be coplanar?

Comment: @copper.hat I think they mean the vectors, not their endpoints

Answer (score 2):

If we set $$A=\begin{pmatrix} v_1 \\ v_2 \\ v_3 \end{pmatrix}\in M_{3\times 3}(F)$$ then $\det(A)$ is the same as $\det(B)$ where $$B=\begin{pmatrix} 4v_1+3v_2 \\ v_2+4v_3 \\ -v_3-v_1 \end{pmatrix}$$ since the [Elementary row operations](http://www.missouriwestern.edu/cas/Math/ElementaryRowOperations.pdf) let us for that.

Comment: Needs an UV ... +1

Comment: Matrices are covered in the next unit, so I'm not expected to solve the problem this way.

Answer (score 0):

You have to set up a system of linear equations and show that there is a non trivial solution. You can start like a*w1 + b*w2 + c* w3 = 0, then substitute the wi with your equations. Then, you get equations in v1,v2,v3 and can find out, whether there is a nontrivial solution by applying the knowledge that v1,v2,v3 are not coplanar:

Solve a*w1+b*w2+c*w3 = 0 for a,b,c:

a (4v1+3v2)+b(v2+4v3)+c(-v1-3v3) = 0

yields: 
v1 (4a-c) + v2 (3a+b) + v3 ( 4b-3c) = 0

and since v1,v2,v3 are not coplanar: 
4a-c = 0 and 3a+b = 0 and 4b-3c = 0
which leads to a = b = c = 0 (c=4a, b = -3a, therefore 0 = 4b-3c = -12a-12a = -24a => a =0; => b =0 => c=0)

Therefore they are not coplanar. 
Sorry for the formatting.